# interface name mismatch bionic ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, netplan

Facing an issue where there is a mismatch in the interface name.
While installation the rename happens from `eth0 to enp3s0` noticed in `/var/log/installer/sys.log` which also generates ethernet name as enp3s0 in `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`. The strange thing is once the server boots up the rename happen from `eth0 to ens160` and no change is made in netcfg file causing the interface to be down.
I have used packer installation for the same.

But on the other hand when I install ubuntu 18 directly from the UI by following all the manual steps there is no issue as such and the rename is similar to the one while installation and then booting up which is `eth0 to ens160`.

On both the above occasions the installation is done on VMware.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the kernel parameters passed at the boot time
`acpi = off`. I used this option specifically to overcome kernel panic issue listed here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1772038. After removing the parameter and only keeping the `nolapic` has solved both the kernel panic and interface naming issue.